# how to specify deferred Sorting on a ListObject

Tags: excel, vba

**Basic Question**
Is there a way to specify a collection of SortFields that can be specified at one time and applied as needed at a later time?

**Background**
I have a large ListObject for which has nine different logical views. Each view has

1. columns that are grouped or ungrouped
2. filtering
3. sorting
4. scrollColumn

I want to apply this concept to several different projects that use a ListObject (LO) and so created a sort of Composite pattern class structure.

This seems to work well but I am running into the following problems with sorting, the biggest being that it seems like you cannot just new up a SortFields object.

What I would like to do is store a SortFields that has already been loaded with the SortField items it requires and then apply that to the ListObject.SortFields when a new view is selected.

Does this make sense. Any implementation ideas?

**UPDATE**
Code expression of concept

```
class ViewComponent
    property Range as Excel.Range      ' group/ungroup, etc
    property Name as String            ' key to finding this component 
    property ScrollColumn as Long
    property ChildViewKeyCollection as Collection  ' IF we are a composite
    property SortFieldCollection as SortFields     ' *** How to?? ***
end class

class ViewComponentManager
    ' manage the component views
end class
```

Comment: Seems like it should work in principle. You can declare variables to be of types like `Sort`, `SortField` and `SortFields` and such variables can be set equal to values, stored in a collection, etc. If there is some sort of difficulty, describe the problem that you are running into. I really have no idea what you mean when you say "you cannot just new up a SortsFields object"

Comment: Type "Dim sfCol As New SortFields" in your editor and then try to compile it. Then type "Dim sf As New SortField" and try and compile that. Let me know what happens

Comment: I see. I have never seen "new" used as a verb that way in VBA, but it makes sense. Maybe to create them you need a parent object, but perhaps once created you can assign them to variables.

Comment: I know you can do it was an array, so don't see why a collection would be any different. I have the code for that, but since it doesn't answer this question, i won't post.

Comment: @HolmesIV. The question is most definitely about implementing a solution given the restricted usage of SortFields. Please post!

Answer (score 0):

Microsofts [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff836133.aspx) of the ListObject.Sort method is pretty useless, but you can use SortFields just like any other object in Excel.

```
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim losort As SortField
Set lo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
Set losort = lo.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A1"))

lo.Sort.Apply
```